# How to query a many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, many-to-many

3 Tables:
Fruits(id, name)
Buckets(id, name)
Bucket_Fruit(id, fruit_id, bucket_id, count)

e.g There's a bucket Bucket1 having 2 apples and 1 banana:

| Fruits.id | Fruits.name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Banana |

| Buckets.id | Buckets.name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bucket1 |

| Bucket_Fruit.id | Bucket_Fruit.fruit_id | Bucket_Fruit.bucket_id | Bucket_Fruit.count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Question is: how to query the bucket which only have exactly 2 apples and 1 banana?
I can guarantee that there wont be 2 buckets which have same fruits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct bucket_id 
from Bucket_Fruit b
where exists (select * from Bucket_Fruit where bucket_id=b.bucket_id 
                                        and fruit_id=(select id from Fruits where name='apple') 
                                        and count=2)
    and exists (select * from Bucket_Fruit where bucket_id=b.bucket_id 
                                        and fruit_id=(select id from Fruits where name='banana') 
                                        and count=1)
    and bucket_id in (select bucket_id from Bucket_Fruit group by bucket_id having count(fruit_id)=2)
;
```